# Wookiee with a "web" belt?

Tags: star-wars

I seem to recall a footnote, conversation, random factoid that a Wookiee (perhaps Chewie or Big Z from KOTOR) has a belt, piece of clothing, or bandoleer made of web/silk from a spider or worm on Kashyyyk.

I've looked everywhere and can't find any reference to such a thing. It's driving me mad!

Does anyone know of any such item in Star Wars lore belonging to a main character Wookiee?

Comment: Could it have been from a game? Often times games have that kind of stuff thrown into random pick-ups.

Comment: It may have been from KOTOR, for sure.

Comment: In the version of KOTOR I played (the iPad version), Big Z wears suspenders and a belt for no apparent reason (belts and suspenders are generally worn in order to keep pants from falling down, but Big Z doesn't wear pants).  However, I have never seen any information in the game (or elsewhere) about where these accessories came from, or what they are made of.  Of course, Zaalbar is notoriously tight-lipped, and even after you help him liberate Kashyyk, he doesn't say much about his planet, his customs, his childhood, or his useless suspender-belt combo.

Comment: He doesn't talk about much of anything before Kashyyk is liberated, and even during/after the liberation, he only talks about his fight with Chuundar, his exile, Bacca's Blade, Wookiee conceptions of honor, and his life debt to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wookiee/Legends#Life_cycle), many Wookiees wear silk belts.

> Around the age of twelve, the males would perform an initiation ritual that made them enter young adulthood. In most parts of Kashyyyk, incumbents to the coming-of-age ritual had to gather silk fibers from the center of a carnivorous syren plant.

[and](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Syren_plant)

> As a rite of passage, many young Wookiees would attempt to harvest the plant's syren fibers at the Well of the Dead. A young Wookiee would bring a few stronger friends to hold the powerful petals in place while the he attempted to harvest the fibers as quickly as possible, which he would then wear as a symbol of virility and bravery.

For example, here's Chewbacca's nephew Lowbacca sporting his stylish silk belt:

[image: Web belt.]

Comment: Och... simultaneous answers. Hate when that happens.

Comment: This one came in one minute sooner and with more info. You were both so helpful though! Both get upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a worm, but there's [this bit](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wookiee/Legends) from Wookieepedia:

> Around the age of twelve, the males would perform an initiation ritual that made them enter young adulthood. In most parts of Kashyyyk, incumbents to the coming-of-age ritual had to gather silk fibers from the center of **a carnivorous [syren plant](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Syren_plant)**.

The source is apparently *[Secrets of Kashyyyk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Secrets_of_Kashyyyk)*.

According to the [syren plant entry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Syren_plant), Lowbacca wears a belt from the those fibers.

[image: Lowbacca]